# Requests module works in Console but not Script - all other modules work normally

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm getting a very strange error w/ the requests library. When I run:

```
>>> import requests
```

in the console it works fine, but when I run the script:

```
import requests
print('done')
```

I get an error that it can't find a related module, utils (believe its email.utils)

```
ImportError: No module named utils
```

All other modules work load normally. Also, it's just in pycharm where the error occurs - things work fine in sublime text. Any thoughts?

Comment: What Python version? Are you using virtualenv? What PYTHON_PATH?

Comment: It is probably `requests.utils`. Is the script run with the same Python version as the interactive interpreter?

Answer (score 2):

You're probably using a different version of python to run the script than you're using for the console. Look at the top of the script. If there's a `#/path/to/python`, that's the python that will be used when you run the script. You can force it to use the same python as your console by doing `python script.py`, assuming `python` is what you normally run to open a console.