# PyCharm error: 'No Module' when trying to import own module (python script)

Tags: python, module, pycharm

I have written a module (a file `my_mod.py` file residing in the folder `my_module`).
Currently, I am working in the file `cool_script.py` that resides in the folder `cur_proj`. I have opened the folder in PyCharm using File -- open (and I assume, hence, it is a PyCharm project).

In ProjectView (CMD-7), I can see my project `cur_proj` (in red) and under "External Libraries" I do see `my_module`. In cool_script.py, I can write

```
from my_module import my_mod as mm
```

and PyCharm even makes suggestion for my_mod. So far so good.

**However, when I try to run cool_script.py, PyCharm tells me
*"No module named my_module"***

This seems strange to me, because

1. in the terminal (OS 10.10.2), in python, I can import the module no problem -- there is a corresponding entry in the PYTHONPATH in .bashrc
2. in PyCharm -- Settings -- Project cur_proj -- Project Interpreter -- CogWheel next to python interpreter -- more -- show paths for selected interpreter icon, the paths from PYTHONPATH do appear (as I think they should)

Hence, why do I get the error when I try to run cool_script.py?  -- **What am I missing?**

Notes:

- I am [not declaring a different / special python version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25150355/requests-module-works-in-console-but-not-script-all-other-modules-work-normall) at the top of cool_script.py
- I made sure that [the path to `my_module` is correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19885821/how-do-i-import-modules-in-pycharm)
- I [put `__init__.py` files (empty files)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12284667/django-error-no-module-named) both in `my_module` and in `cur_proj`
- I am not using `virtualenv`

## Addendum 2015-Feb-25

When I go in PyCharm to Run -- Edit Configurations, for my current project, there are two options that are selected with a check mark: "*Add content roots to PYTHONPATH*" and "*Add source roots to PYTHONPATH*". When I have both unchecked, I can load my module.

So it works now -- **but why**?

Further questions emerged:

- What are "content roots" and what are "source roots"? And why does adding something to the PYTHONPATH make it somehow break?
- should I uncheck both of those options all the time (so also in the defaults, not only the project specific configurations (left panel of the Run/Debug Configurations dialog)?

Comment: You may have already tried this but when importing modules from other packages, include packagename `from foldername.mymodule import mymethod`. Another thing I've had to do is to add the empty __init_.py folder in all the folders that you would use to get to your module so in case of `from parentfolder.childfolder.mymodule ...` you would need init in two folders. Depending on where the folders are located relative to each other you might need to have a top level package in `sys.path` as described in this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8951255/import-script-from-a-parent-directory)

Comment: I had your problem too. The following post solved my issues: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21236824/unresolved-reference-issue-in-pycharm

Comment: What worked for me is unchecking `Enable Django Support` in the settings `Languages & Frameworks -> Django` in the Pro version of PyCharm. It was opening a django console which caused the import issues.

Comment: If you are coming here with a locally developed library and importing a newly added module running `pip install -e .` again  in the terminal solved my issue.

Comment: I'm removing the duplicate closure to ["ImportError: No module named" when trying to run Python script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15514593/7758804) because the issue here has to do with settings in PyCharm, which is not the same resolution(s) offered in answers to the other question.

Answer (score 415):

If your own module is in the same path, you need mark the path as `Sources Root`. In the project explorer, right-click on the directory that you want import. Then select `Mark Directory As` and select `Sources Root`.

Comment: This worked for me but I also had to delete and re-create the run configuration that I had previously created before marking the folder as sources root.

Comment: And need add `__init__.py` to make Python treat the directories as containing packages: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for#answer-448279

Comment: How would you do this if you weren't using pycharm? I'm running into the exact same problem.

Comment: @BeatrizFonseca Yes I did. I couldn't get it to work in sublime, but I installed pycharm and tried the answer here and it worked perfectly fine, so it must have something to do with specifying the right directory as the root package.

Comment: @BoudewijnAasman you could try use `.` before package name to specify that this package is local one

Comment: Why is it necessary if the module is in the same path? If my module is in a sub-directory and I mark the parent directory as Sources Root, I'd think it can find module?

Comment: @BeatrizFonseca What does marking folder as `Sources Root` do internally in Pycharm? does it add the directory path to `PYTHONPATH` ?

Comment: No, in the PyCharm docs, Source Root is used to resolve imports. I do not know if the path is added to `PYTHONPATH`
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/content-root.html#root_types

Comment: @jaggi it adds the path to `PYTHONPATH` which you can check with `print(os.environ['PYTHONPATH'])`. Initially you'll have something like /Users/user/PycharmProjects/test_stuff. And after you mark the folder `Sources Root` you'll see something like /Users/user/PycharmProjects/test_stuff:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/test_stuff/package_1

Answer (score 74):

So if you go to

-> Setting -> Project:My_project -> Project Structure,

Just the directory in which the source code is available and mark it as "Sources" (You can see it on the same window). The directory with source code should turn blue. Now u can import in modules residing in same directory.

Answer (score 35):

## PyCharm Community/Professional 2018.2.1

I was having this problem just now and I was able to solve it in sort of a similar way that @Beatriz Fonseca and @Julie pointed out.

If you go to `File` -> `Settings` -> `Project: YourProjectName` -> `Project Structure`, you'll have a directory layout of the project you're currently working in. You'll have to go through your directories and label them as being either the `Source` directory for all your Source files, or as a `Resource` folder for files that are strictly for importing.

You'll also want to make sure that you place `__init__.py` files within your resource directories, or really anywhere that you want to import from, and it'll work perfectly fine.

Comment: This is not specific to *PyCharm Professional*, rather this feature is available in *PyCharm Community* edition as well. In the Project Structure, right-click the directory containing the module then select `Mark Directory as` from the context menu and select `Sources Root`.

Comment: Can you please advise what is meaning of this Sources Root. Though it solved my problem but didn't quite understand why i am doing it.

Answer (score 12):

What I tried is to source the location where my files are.

e.g. `E:\git_projects\My_project\__init__.py is my location.`

I went to File -> Setting -> Project:My_project -> Project Structure and added the content root to about mention place `E:\git_projects\My_project`

it worked for me.

Answer (score 12):

**Always mark as source root the directory ABOVE the import!**

So if the structure is

`parent_folder/src/module.py`

you must put something like:

`from src.module import function_inside_module`

and have `parent_folder` marked as "source folder" in PyCharm

Comment: Weird.. I marked the equivalent of `src` as source folder but then using your `src.module` solved it for me! Thanks, although I am still confused

Answer (score 7):

I was getting the error with "Add source roots to PYTHONPATH" as well. My problem was that I had two folders with the same name, like `project/subproject1/thing/src` and `project/subproject2/thing/src` and I had both of them marked as source root. When I renamed one of the `"thing"` folders to `"thing1"` (any unique name), it worked.

Maybe if PyCharm automatically adds selected source roots, it doesn't use the full path and hence mixes up folders with the same name.

Answer (score 5):

`my_module` is a folder not a module and you can't import a folder, try moving `my_mod.py` to the same folder as the `cool_script.py` and then do`import my_mod as mm`. This is because python only looks in the current directory and `sys.path`, and so wont find `my_mod.py` unless it's in the same directory

Or you can look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder-in-python) for an answer telling you how to import from other directories.

As to your other questions, I do not know as I do not use PyCharm.

Comment: You can create a __init__.py in a folder, python interpreter will read as python package: http://mikegrouchy.com/blog/2012/05/be-pythonic-__init__py.html

Answer (score 4):

This can be caused when Python interpreter can't find your code. You have to mention explicitly to Python to find your code in this location.

To do so:

- Go to your python console
- Add `sys.path.extend(['your module location'])` to Python console.

In your case:

- Go to your python console,
- On the start, write the following code:

  ```
  import sys
  sys.path.extend([my module URI location])
  ```
- Once you have written this statement you can run following command:

  ```
  from mymodule import functions
  ```

Answer (score 4):

The key confusing step that must be done is to recreate the run configuration for the source file that you're trying to execute, so that the IDE picks up the new paths.

The way that actually worked for me was to go to Run/Edit Configurations..., select the configuration for the file that you're trying to run on the left side, uncheck the "Add source roots to PYTHONPATH" box, save, and then go back and check the box and save.  THEN it would work.

Answer (score 2):

The solution for this problem without having to Mark Directory as Source Root is to Edit Run Configurations and in Execution select the option "Redirect input from" and choose script you want to run. This works because it is then treated as if the script was run interactively in this directory. However Python will still mark the module name with an error "no module named x":

[image: Redirect input from:]

When the interpreter executes the import statement, it searches for x.py in a list of directories assembled from the following sources:

1. The directory from which the input script was run or the current directory if the interpreter is being run interactively
2. The list of directories contained in the PYTHONPATH environment variable, if it is set.
3. An installation-dependent list of directories configured at the time Python is installed, in my case usr/lib/python3.6 on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

## PyCharm 2021.2.4  -- March 4th, 2022

Solved it by marking the source directory as "Source". Accomplished it by

- right clicking on the source directory in the Project structure on the left of the IDE. I had a code source named **src/**.
- navigate to "Mark Directory as".
- select "Source" as directory type.

In short,

`src -> Mark Directory as -> Source`

Answer (score 2):

This can occur if you are running a python file with the same name as one of its parent directories and try to import another

e.g.

Say you have files

```
my_project/processing/method1/processing.py
my_project/processing/algorithms/predict.py
```

And in processing.py you do something like:

`from my_project.processing.algorithms.predict import Predict`

it will throw the error

Answer (score 1):

Content roots are folders holding your project code while source roots are defined as same too. The only difference i came to understand was that the code in source roots is built before the code in the content root.

Unchecking them wouldn't affect the runtime till the point you're not making separate modules in your package which are manually connected to Django. That means if any of your files do not hold the 'from django import...' or any of the function isn't called via django, unchecking these 2 options will result in a malfunction.

Update - the problem only arises when using Virtual Environmanet, and only when controlling the project via the provided terminal. Cause the terminal still works via the default system pyhtonpath and not the virtual env. while the python django control panel works fine.

Answer (score 0):

ln -s . someProject

If you have someDirectory/someProjectDir and two files, file1.py and file2.py, and  file1.py tries to import with this line

from someProjectDir import file2

It won't work, even if you have designated the someProjectDir as a source directory, and even if it shows in preferences, project, project structure menu as a content root. The only way it will work is by linking the project as show above (unix command, works in mac, not sure of use or syntax for Windows).
There seems some mechanism where Pycharm does this automatically either in checkout from version control or adding as context root, since the soft link was created by Pycharm in a dependent project. Hence, just copying the same, although the weird replication of directory is annoying and necessity is perplexing. Also in the dependency where auto created, it doesn't show as new directory under version control. Perhaps comparison of .idea files will reveal more.