# Kivy 1.9.1 on pycharm ubuntu: ImportError: No module named _clock

Tags: python, ubuntu, pycharm, kivy

I'm trying to execute kivy 1.9.1 examples in Ubuntu 14.

Running the examples from command line gave me the error:

```
ImportError: No module named _clock
```

Downloading kivy source code from git, and checking the installed packages in the virtualenv directories, I found the _clock.so file was missing in the  venvs/kivyinstall/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy folder.

So, I went into the kivy_sorce/kivy folder, and create a simple setup.py to execute with cython to get de .so compiled version:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
  name = 'clock',
  ext_modules = cythonize("_clock.pyx"),
)
```

and

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

Then I copied the resulting .so file into my virtual environment in the expected folder venvs/kivyinstall/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy.

Now, examples run from command line (activating virtual environment),

`python examples/demo/pictures/main.py`

And it also runs properly from pycharm's python console (I previosly configured as python interpreter the python executable from my kivy-install venv) executing this:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['python', 'examples/demo/pictures/main.py'])
```

Pycharm seems to find the package cause the kivy._clock import appear no more in red, but if I execute the example directly from pycharm (ctrl+shift+F10), it keeps asking for the missing kivy._clock module.

Any hint about why pycharm still can't find the module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried marking the kivy and examples folders as "Sources" as recommended
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28705029/pycharm-error-no-module-when-trying-to-import-own-module-python-script).

But it didn't work, finally, unchecking the "*add source roots to PYTHONPATH*" option in running configuration in the **Run -> Edit configurations** menu did the trick.

Hope it helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

This happens sometimes when PyCharm's internal cache is out-of-sync with what is on the disk.

It usually corrects itself, but you can force it from <kbd>File</kbd>→ <kbd>Invalidate caches / Restart...</kbd>