# simple import in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

I've read [PEP 328](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/#guido-s-decision) and similar questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981921/relative-imports-in-python-3), but they still didn't answer my questions about python 3 import. My question is:

why does a single dot `.` relative import ever produce an error like the following?

code: (`__init__.py` exists in the same directory)

```
from . import module_x
```

error:

```
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

Yes, there are workarounds to get around of this error for example by running `python -m` from the parent directory, but why?

Shouldn't `.` always refer to the same directory of the current module and the example *always* works as long as the `module_x` exists in the same directory?

Particularly `PyCharm` tries to run `unittest` test cases from the directory where the test file is, and would always fail the `.` import. Some may argue it's `PyCharm`'s problem, but I think a simple import like this should really *always* work regardless where the interpreter runs.

Answer (score 0):

There is a detailed answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981921/relative-imports-in-python-3), also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28705029/pycharm-error-no-module-when-trying-to-import-own-module-python-script). Sorry I cannot write this as a comment.

Comment: The 1st link is one of the workarounds I looked at. The 2nd link doesn't work for my case. I had to change the `Working Directory` setting in `PyCharm` to point to the parent directory. Nevertheless, I'm wondering why such workarounds are needed for `.` imports.

Comment: That will require a detailed analysis. I remember having the problem with pycharm a year ago, after that I used the package name instead of dot. Relative path imports messed up my project.